# What does "Top level reordering" mean?

Tags: optimization, fortran, mpi, gfortran

I have an open MPI code for Fortran, which compiles and runs without errors when using no optimization flags. When I swith on the -O1 flag, there is a Segmentation Fault error at the execution time. The only optimization flag that causes this problem is *-ftoplevel-reorder*. Can you intuitively explain what this flag does and what the best strategy is for spotting a bug in the code (if any)?

Comment: Have you tried using standard debugging flags? Compile-time warnings and run-time checks?

Answer (score 4):

from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

```
-fno-toplevel-reorder

    Do not reorder top-level functions, variables, and asm statements. Output them in the same order that they appear in the input file. When this option is used, unreferenced static variables are not removed. This option is intended to support existing code that relies on a particular ordering. For new code, it is better to use attributes when possible.

    Enabled at level -O0. When disabled explicitly, it also implies -fno-section-anchors, which is otherwise enabled at -O0 on some targets.
```

you might be accessing an array out of bounds, and depending on how local variables are put on the stack, the consequences span from unnoticeable to a fatal crash.

Comment: In that case the debugging flags mentioned by Ross should by used first before testing each optimization flag.